# Парсинг лог файла в динамике и вывод на фронт

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Разрабатывается проект на Django. Установлен DRF.
В ходе работы одного из процессов Backend-a  генерится лог, который необходимо парсить и, выловив нужную строку, вывести на HTML страницу пользователя. Все происходит в динамике.

Вот код, который я написал.
urls.py

```
    path('api/log-stream/', LogStreamAPIView.as_view(), name='log_stream'),
```

Вот часть вьюхи

```
class LogStreamAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        def stream_log():
            f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', rcvenot_log], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            p = select.poll()
            p.register(f.stdout)

            while TEST_IN_PROGRESS:
                if p.poll(0.1):
                    new_line_log = f.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
                    for target_line in RCV_SCENARIO:
                        if target_line in new_line_log:
                            yield f"event: {new_line_log}\n\n"

        return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Вот часть на стороне HTML

```
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <ul id="logList"></ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var logList = document.getElementById('logList');

                function updateLog(newLine) {
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = newLine;
                    logList.appendChild(listItem);
                }

                var source = new EventSource('/api/log-stream/');
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    updateLog(event.data);
                };
            });
        </script>
```

В ходе работы при переходе на `mysite.ru/api/log-stream/` я вижу, что строки выдаются,
`event: 2024.03.22 16:16:13:016[INFO ][Thread-0] РџРѕР»СѓС‡РµРЅРѕ СѓРІРµРґРѕРјР»РµРЅРёРµ РѕР± РёР·РјРµРЅРµРЅРёСЏС…, РєРѕР»РёС‡РµСЃС‚РІРѕ РјРѕРґРёС„РёС†РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРЅС‹С… СЌР»РµРјРµРЅС‚РѕРІ - 2`

но на странице пользователя они не появляются.

Прошу помочь разобраться в чем может быть проблема.

PS
Я читал что EventSource может быть "чувствителен" к формату данных и ему нужно именно в формате `f"event: {new_line_log}\n\n"` или `f"data: {new_line_log}\n\n"`. Пробовал и так и так, не работает

PSS
Если еще подскажите по поводу проблемы кодировки, буду благодарен. Эту проблему еще не курил.

[image: Скриншот консоли браузера]

Comment: Начните с проверки ошибки и открытия соединения `source.onerror = (e) => console.error(e);` ну и убедитесь, что соединение открывается `source.onopen = (e) => console.log('open', e);`

Comment: Вижу ошибку в консоли браузера:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/log-stream/ 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: Однако не понимаю в чем проблема...
Там должны быть хитрые заголовки?

Добавил 
var source = new EventSource('/api/log-stream/', { headers: { 'Accept': 'text/event-stream' } });

Все тоже самое

Comment: В описание SSE сказано, что сервер должен вернут код 200 в обязательном порядке. Проверьте во вкладке network, какой код присылае сервер

Comment: На сколько я понимаю 200 и присылает. Но крайне боюсь обмануть, потому вниз вопроса добавлю скрин из консоли

Comment: Вот ткните на строчку log-stream и посмотрите во кладках, что там приходит

Comment: В response вижу 
{"detail":"Невозможно удовлетворить \"Accept\" заголовок запроса."}

Но не указано почему и что не нравится...

Comment: Ну далее я пас. Я python не знаю, а надо как раз заставить серверную часть ответить с кодом 200 и нужным заголовком. Клиентская часть пока ведет себя корректно и нашли ошибку(теперь вы хотябы понимаете, что там происходит) P.S. добавьте скрин из вкладки network - нужна вкладка headers

Comment: При этом в Headers стоит Accept: text/event-stream

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо большое!

Comment: @SwaD вопрос... Читаю SSE, сервер должен ответить Content-Type: text/event-stream, а я в консоли браузера вижу Content-Type: application/json

Не может ли быть тут ошибка?

Comment: А что есть сделать так: `StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream', status=200)`

Comment: status=200 не помог...

Comment: @SwaD решил проблему с кодом ответа. Тайна крылась в особенностях обработки запросов DRF. Вот тут описано решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78210488/getting-wrong-sse-response-from-the-server/78210808#78210808. Однако это не решило проблему появления строк на HTML странице пользовател.

Comment: Оформите новый вопрос, добавив туда измененный код. Так же на фронте добавьте `console.log(event)` в onmessage перед вызовом функции updateLog

Answer (score 0):

1. Тайна крылась в особенностях обработки запросов DRF. Вот тут описано решение stackoverflow.com/questions/78210488/…. Это решило проблему получения кода 406 и получить нормальный ответ 200.
2. Данные необходимо передавать в формате f"data: {data}\n\n."  Это требование SSE