# Некорректный код ответа SSE

Tags: python, html, django, sse

Вопрос в продолжении этого:
[Парсинг лог файла в динамике и вывод на фронт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572829/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82)

Кратко суть: В ходе работы одного из процессов Backend-a генерится лог, который необходимо парсить и, выловив нужную строку, вывести на HTML страницу пользователя. Все происходит в динамике.

По api сервер отвечает вот так:

```
return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

В консоли браузера получаю код ответа 406: `GET 127.0.0.1:8000/api/log-stream 406 (Not Acceptable)`

[image: Скриншот консоли браузера]

[image: Скриншот консоли баузера]

В response вижу `{"detail":"Невозможно удовлетворить \"Accept\" заголовок запроса."}`

Что пробовал, но не помогло:

1. Менять формат ответа yield f"event: {new_line_log}\n\n" и yield f"data: {new_line_log}\n\n"
2. Добавлять status на ответ `return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream’s , status=200)` и `status=202`

Так же прочитал описание SSE, сервер должен ответить `Content-Type: text/event-stream`, а я в консоли браузера вижу `Content-Type: application/json`. Подозреваю не может ли быть тут ошибка...

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Тайна крылась в особенностях обработки запросов DRF. Вот тут описано решение stackoverflow.com/questions/78210488/…. Это решило проблему получения кода 406 и получить нормальный ответ 200, однако это не решило проблему появления строк на HTML странице пользователя.